# Script creates data validation, "requireValueInRange" forces absolute references?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script to update an input sheet and adding validation rules, but I'm struggling with restraining items to be in a range.

Let's say I want to create a rule restraining the range A1:A10 to items in the column below the cells, so A1 must be an item in B1:1, A2 in B2:2, etc.

I can manually create such a rule with `=MySheet!B$2:B$1000`, but I can't do so with the scripting api, because it uses absolute references (so `=MySheet!$B$2:$B$1000`).

Here is my code so far (ignore the range numbers, not part of the question):

```
var playerDeckValidation = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation()
  .requireValueInRange(gamesValidationDataSheet.getRange(2, 1 + 6 * gameCount, 999))
  .build();
gamesSheet.getRange(gameRow + 1, 4, 1, 6).setDataValidation(playerDeckValidation);
```

But as I mentioned, this will produce the rule `=PartiesValidationData!$G$2:$G$1000` where I would like `=PartiesValidationData!G$2:G$1000`.

I've been looking through [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requireValueInRange(Range)) for a bit now, but it does not state very well the full behavior of the function.

Did I missed something ? Do I even have a way to create a data validation rule that have a different range for each cell ?

(I know I can create one validation rule per cell for my whole range with the scripting API, but I want to be sure there is no way to build it properly before bloating the data validation rule count)

Comment: I looked into an issue report on the [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/182575830) discussing the change in `requireValueInRange` notation from relative to absolute. It's labeled as an intended behavior, but there's no additional explanation in the thread. Cooper suggested trying [`requireValueInList`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/data-validation-builder#requirevalueinlistvalues) as a potential solution. Do you think this could work for your situation?

Comment: Thanks for the research, unfortunately I really need to get the elements from a range as it is dynamic and can be changed after the script has executed.